# Eureka lease interval not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I have a eureka server and a bunch of clients/instances. I had set the properties:

```
eureka.instance.leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds=120
eureka.instance.leaseExpirationDurationInSeconds=240
```

to all the clients/instances. I found that when I stop a client, the eureka dashboard updates the status as DOWN in 30 seconds itself instead of 240. How can I simulate the scenario where even if a client is down, the Eureka server comes to know about it only after 240 seconds?

Comment: Are you sure, the interval is not honored? I would expect, that the lease time is a maximum time-span. If 210 seconds are over and you stop the service, you will see a DOWN within 30 seconds.

Comment: @Jonathan I am not sure I understand the lease time concept. I thought once a client is registered, it keeps sending heartbeat every 30 secs. If I change that interval to 120 then it sends heartbeats every 120 secs. So if I stop a client, the server is going to wait for 120 secs to receive a heartbeat. That means for that 120 secs, the server should consider the client as UP even though in reality it is down.

Comment: You are right but consider the following case: Heartbeat signals between server and app are exchanged. Nothing happens for 90 seconds. You kill the app. 30 seconds later 120s since last heartbeat have passed and the app is marked as DOWN.